# What is the correct syntax for calling this completion handler?

Tags: swift, branch.io

I am getting an error while using the below code.

Here's my code:

```
let params = [ "referringUsername": "vihar",
                   "referringUserId": "78457" ]

Branch.getInstance().getShortURL(withParams: params, andChannel: "SMS", andFeature: "Referral", andCallback: { (url: String!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
    if (error == nil) {

        let vc = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [url], applicationActivities: [])
        self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)

    } else {
        print("Genrate Error")
    }
})
```

I am getting this error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(String!, NSError!) -> Void' to expected argument type 'callbackWithUrl!' (aka 'ImplicitlyUnwrappedOptional<(Optional<String>, Optional<Error>) -> ()>')

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
Branch.getInstance().getShortURL(withParams: params, andChannel: "SMS", 
 andFeature: "Referral", andCallback: { (url: String!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
```

with

```
Branch.getInstance().getShortURL(withParams: params, andChannel: "SMS",
andFeature: "Referral", andCallback: { (url, error) in
```

Comment: @Sh_Khan could you add an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

Branch.getInstance().getShortURL(withParams: params, andChannel: "SMS",
andFeature: "Referral", andCallback: { (url, error) in
share

as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.branch.io/pages/viral/content-sharing/#creating-dynamic-links-without-the-share-sheet)

For any further questions, write to integration@branch.io.